# Como salvar arquivos no armazenamento externo do Android (como cartão da san disk)?

Tags: android

Então o problema que estou enfrentando é que estou querendo salvar um arquivo .txt no cartão de memoria do Android, acontece que quando tento executar o FileOutputStream.Write() ele da a seguinte mensagem:

> /mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

**Meu Código**:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
File file = new File("/mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt");
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write(textView.getText().toString().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
    Log.e("TAG", file.getAbsolutePath() + " Arquivo Criado");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

Já verifiquei onde poderia haver possíveis erros como:

- A falta da permissão no manifest:

  ```
  ...
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.febatis.texto">

          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

          <application
                  ...
          </application>
  </manifest>
  ```
- Não ter pedido permissão em tempo de execução para leitura e gravação (Sendo chamado no OnCreate() da minha MainActivity:

  ```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
          if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
                  requestPermissions(new String[]{
                          Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                  }, 0);
          }
  }
  ```
- Não ter testado em diretório sem arquivo e com arquivo com o mesmo nome existente.

  ```
  File file = new File("/mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt");
  File file = new File("/mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos")
  ```

(Funciona para leitura)

```
File file = new File("storage/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt");
```

Bom, não sei o que posso fazer para conseguir acesso ao cartão de memoria externo do Android.